# Not able to assign a value to a variable

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, variable-assignment, python-3.6, namedtuple

I've been playing around with namedtuples from collections in classes, and came across this simpler 'syntactic sugar' naming assignment, but when I assign foo to 009 and try to put it into the tuple it doesn't work. Am I simple, or can someone explain to me this is borken, and the snakes will not eat me for missing the obvious?

```
foo = 999
#foo = 009

var = main, x, y, z, a = 'this', 10, 9, 8, foo

print('content: ', var)
print(main)
print(a, x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to create an int starting with `0`. If you wish to create an int that is the equivalent of 9, you should just write `foo = 9`.

0 as a prefix is used for special cases such as `0x<number>` for hexadecimal and `0o<number>` for octal integers.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't make foo = 009 because python doesn't support that. Try this:

```
foo = 999
foo = 9

var = main, x, y, z, a = 'this', 10, 9, 8, foo

print('content: ', var)
print(main)
print(a, x, y, z)
```